# Java Map empty string value is omitted when sending response to postman

Tags: java, rest, dictionary

My map is : Map<String, String>. The issue is empty values are not sended to the postman even though when I debbug are there.

This is the api :

```
@GetMapping(value = Routes.URI_SUFFIX_DATA_ZIPCODES_BY_CITY_AND_ZIPCODE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@RegisterMetricCallReceived(appService = "getStreetsByCityAndZipCode", version = "v1", type = TYPE_REST)
public Map<String,String> getStreetsByCityAndZipCode(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                               @RequestParam(name = "city") String city,
                                                               @RequestParam(name = "zipcode") String zipcode) {

        GetStreetByCityAndZipcode query = new GetStreetByCityAndZipcode();
        query.setCity(city);
        query.setZipcode(zipcode);
        Map<String, String> result = service.getStreets("eligibility", query).orElse(null);
        return result;
    }
```

When I debugg result object , it's like that :

```
"PLACE DU PRIEURE" -> "01043406"
"ROUTE DE BIERNE" -> ""
"ROUTE DE GENNES SUR GLAIZE" -> "01043405"
"RUE COURTE" -> "01043399"
"RUE D ANJOU" -> "01043398"
"RUE DE GENNES" -> "04311435"
"RUE DE L EGLISE" -> "01043397"
"RUE DE LA CHENAIE" -> "04106244"
"RUE DE LA POSTE" -> "01043400"
"RUE DES GRANDS JARDINS" -> "01043401"
"RUE DES JARDINS" -> ""
"RUE DES SPORTS" -> "04415887"
```

But from postman, I don't receive this two :

```
"ROUTE DE BIERNE" -> ""
"RUE DES JARDINS" -> ""
```

I receive just others which have not empty values:

```
"PLACE DU PRIEURE" -> "01043406"
"ROUTE DE GENNES SUR GLAIZE" -> "01043405"
"RUE COURTE" -> "01043399"
"RUE D ANJOU" -> "01043398"
"RUE DE GENNES" -> "04311435"
"RUE DE L EGLISE" -> "01043397"
"RUE DE LA CHENAIE" -> "04106244"
"RUE DE LA POSTE" -> "01043400"
"RUE DES GRANDS JARDINS" -> "01043401"
"RUE DES SPORTS" -> "04415887"
```

Comment: Are you sure that happens on the headers of the http response, and it's not rather some settings of postman like don't show blank values? Normally if you correctly insert the header then it should be there even if value is empty, you can easily test this by getting the response and printing all the headers code wise (without relying on postman or any other rest client which may be applying some further setting)

Comment: Normally if you correctly insert the header then it should be there even if value is empty => Can you explain what do you mean by insert correctly the header please ?

Comment: Check whether you have this property enabled in your `application.properties` file `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_empty` or `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` if yes, the remove this property and try again.

Comment: I already search for those properties but I didn't find them inside project.

Comment: Instead of postman, try doing the same request with curl and check the content of the headers. Are the empty values there?

Comment: It gives : $ curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/v1/streetsByCityAndZipcode?city=CHATELAIN&zipcode=53200"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2091    0  2091    0     0   1731      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  1730{"ALLEE DES POMMIERS":"04469046","BELLEVUE":"01043345","CHATEAU DE MISE":"01043376","CHATEAU DE MORTRAISE":"01043346","CHEMIN DES VALLEES":"03950740","FERME DE MORTRAISE":"04214242", ...}   without empty values

Comment: Ok, so it seems spring doing that. You confirm that before you return, your map contains the keys with empty values?

Comment: Yes, I confirm.

Comment: Anyway, it's definitely about the serializer used for the map by spring. You have at least two options here, either you return your own class instead of Map<String, String> (and in that object you annotate the map property to include empty values), or you customize the map serializer by injecting your own JsonSerializer for map into the spring 's object mapper (there may be a spring property done for that already but I don't know it by hearth)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was due to this Bean config, when I remove it, it works as fine (or change SerializationInclusion to m.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS)) :

```
 @Bean
 public JacksonFix jacksonFix(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter 
                                           annotationMethodHandlerAdapter) {
        return new JacksonFix(annotationMethodHandlerAdapter);
 }
```

```
public class JacksonFix {
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;

    public JacksonFix(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter) {
        this.annotationMethodHandlerAdapter = annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = this.annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.getMessageConverters();
        Iterator var2 = messageConverters.iterator();

        while(var2.hasNext()) {
            HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter = (HttpMessageConverter)var2.next();
            if (messageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter m = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)messageConverter;
                m.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
            }
        }

    }
}
```